# Selected table cell text show in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a project I'm trying to develop a online ticketing system where I want to read the the Data from selected cell on a table [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/4Ltjqw0n/) .

**FE:** If someone select A1 seat Number the Ticket span should show the Number If selected multiple value the span show the selected multiple ticket number. Please visit my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/4Ltjqw0n/) to see what I'm trying to achieve

```js
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
      isHighlighted,
      tickets = [];
  $("#ticket-board .select")
  .mousedown(function () {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
    selected();
    return false; // prevent text selection
  })

  .mouseover(function () {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      selected();
    }
  });

  $(document)
  .mouseup(function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
    //alert('Deselected');
  });
});

function selected() {
  tickets = $("#ticket-board .select.highlighted").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
  });
  $('.selected-ticket').html(tickets.get().join());
}
```

```css
table .select {
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
table .selected {
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color:#60fc60;
}

.ticket-panel{
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticket-panel">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ticket-board">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class="select">A1</td><td class="select">A2</td><td></td><td class="select">A3</td><td class="select">A4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">B1</td><td class="selected">B2</td><td></td><td class="select">B3</td><td class="select">B4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">C1</td><td class="select">C2</td><td></td><td class="select">C3</td><td class="select">C4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">D1</td><td class="select">D2</td><td></td><td class="select">D3</td><td class="select">D4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">E1</td><td class="select">E2</td><td></td><td class="select">E3</td><td class="select">E4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">F1</td><td class="select">F2</td><td></td><td class="select">F3</td><td class="select">F4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">G1</td><td class="select">G2</td><td></td><td class="select">G3</td><td class="select">G4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">H1</td><td class="select">H2</td><td></td><td class="select">H3</td><td class="select">H4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">I1</td><td class="select">I2</td><td></td><td class="select">I3</td><td class="select">I4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">J1</td><td class="select">J2</td><td class="select">J5</td><td class="select">J3</td><td class="select">J4</td></tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>

  <div class="ticket-data">
    <br>
    <p>Ticket: <span class="selected-ticket"></span></p> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you find your answer, mark one of them to finishing this discussion.

Comment: is it possible put them in a input field instead of <span>

Comment: Yes, see http://jsfiddle.net/4Ltjqw0n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select every `highlighted` class and add value of them to `span`. Like this code

```
var ticketValue = "";
$("#ticket-board td.highlighted").each(function(){
    ticketValue += $(this).text() + ",";
});
$(".selected-ticket").text(ticketValue);
```

You can see demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ltjqw0n/1/)

Comment: Is it possible to count how many ticket is selected ? Actually I'm new in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can get the texts of the selected cell using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
      isHighlighted,
      tickets = [];
  $("#ticket-board .select")
  .mousedown(function () {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
    selected();
    return false; // prevent text selection
  })

  .mouseover(function () {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      selected();
    }
  });

  $(document)
  .mouseup(function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
    //alert('Deselected');
  });
});

function selected() {
  tickets = $("#ticket-board .select.highlighted").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
  });
  $('.selected-ticket').html(tickets.get().join());
}
```

```css
table .select {
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
table .selected {
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color:#60fc60;
}

.ticket-panel{
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticket-panel">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ticket-board">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class="select">A1</td><td class="select">A2</td><td></td><td class="select">A3</td><td class="select">A4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">B1</td><td class="selected">B2</td><td></td><td class="select">B3</td><td class="select">B4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">C1</td><td class="select">C2</td><td></td><td class="select">C3</td><td class="select">C4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">D1</td><td class="select">D2</td><td></td><td class="select">D3</td><td class="select">D4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">E1</td><td class="select">E2</td><td></td><td class="select">E3</td><td class="select">E4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">F1</td><td class="select">F2</td><td></td><td class="select">F3</td><td class="select">F4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">G1</td><td class="select">G2</td><td></td><td class="select">G3</td><td class="select">G4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">H1</td><td class="select">H2</td><td></td><td class="select">H3</td><td class="select">H4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">I1</td><td class="select">I2</td><td></td><td class="select">I3</td><td class="select">I4</td></tr>
      <tr> <td class="select">J1</td><td class="select">J2</td><td class="select">J5</td><td class="select">J3</td><td class="select">J4</td></tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>

  <div class="ticket-data">
    <br>
    <p>Ticket: <span class="selected-ticket"></span></p> 

  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34ueotjz/